Running another thread group after 1st thread group completes using if controller
I have an requirement in which 3 requests/thread group are there, so the thing is when 1st request completes then it generates an output file so that out put file we need to put in the second thread group/request. So what we need to do here is,

We should take a step like as soon as the out put file is generated the same out put file gets attached in the 2nd thread group under CSV data config.

2.also we need to put a condition that if 1st request gets completed then we should wait for 2 minutes then 2nd req should strt automatically.
I am attaching the script which i have prepared. create is 1st request, update is 2nd req and release is 3rd req.
enter image description here
enter image description here
I tried using if controller in the 2nd thread group with the condition but its not working ${__groovy((vars.get('responseCode').equals('404') && vars.get('responseMessage').equals('Not Found')),)}.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I guess you need to amend your If Controller's condition to check the certain file's presence, something like:
${__groovy(new File('/path/to/your/file.txt').exists(),)}

because your condition does something absolutely different.
Alternative option is going for Inter-Thread Communication Plugin, check out SynchronizationExample.jmx test plan for reference implementation
